# Teaching Arkham Horror to new players

Tags: arkham-horror, teaching

I am teaching the game to a ton of new people this week. I was going to be playing with only 3 others and planned to join in myself, but now that we're up to 8 players including me, I figured the game would be more fun if I keep things moving as a non-player Arkham Master. Staying out of the game as a player and act as rules guardian, referee for things 1st player normally resolves, reader of cards, and general knowledge base.

My concern here is on teaching the game quickly without making the players feel like I'm leaving out important decision making details.  Arkham has a lot of rules, is there a new player cheat sheet or anything? If not what rules would you say a player MUST know if an experienced player is moderating the game? My intuition says to explain skills sliders, skill checks, phases, derived checks such as combat and horror, movement points, clues, closing, sealing, and otherworlds and the win/lose conditions for the game.  Has anyone taken the time to teach new players AH more than a few times?  What process do you use to explain the game?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you recommend putting in an Arkham Horror quick reference sheet?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5415/what-do-you-recommend-putting-in-an-arkham-horror-quick-reference-sheet)

Comment: Also related: [What can I do to ensure that my friends' first game of Arkham Horror with me is as awesome as possible?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/what-can-i-do-to-ensure-that-my-friends-first-game-of-arkham-horror-with-me-is)

Answer (score 2):

If you are acting as a guardian, you can *simplify* a bit the part about the monsters movement  as you will do it and focus more on the parts of the turn their players **can actually do** an action.

Giving them a *quick reference card* **before** you explain the things can help them follow better your explanation.

Also with many new people I'd maybe do a *pre prepared* sample turn with just 2 or 3 characters and monsters to show them the mechanics of the game.